# Invoke a form on windows lock screen through some button (manual intervention)

Tags: winapi, winlogon, gina

I am trying to create a button on windows (win xp or win 7 and onwards) which can open up a form.

I am able to do that by overriding **Utilman.exe** by owning it and replacing it with my custom exe renamed as Utilman.exe, but that will suppress the existing features provided by the operating system.

I have looked upon creating custom **GINA** but not sure if I can achieve the same with it.

If there is any sample or pointers available please provide.

**Problem:** 
On windows logon screen I need to provide a button which can invoke a form (with the machine still locked), something like in the below image:

[image]

Comment: XP used GINA. Vista introduced a new credentials API that replaced GINA. You need to pick XP or Vista and concentrate on one at a time. It's no good to ask about both in one question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan is it possible with winlogon and credentials api on Vista and onwards ? can you please provide some pointers on this ?

Comment: I'm not sure whether or not it is supported with credentials API. What I think some people do (e.g. hardware manufacturers) is run a local system service and hack their way into the lock screen UI from there. Why do you want to do this anyway?

Comment: Windows 8 and above offers limited support to customize the lock screen. See [Lock screen overview (Windows Runtime apps)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779720.aspx) to get details, on what can (and what cannot) be customized.